# QList, appending object, loosing static members

Tags: c++, qlist

I'm using building a `QList` in my object:

```
QList<clsXMLnode*> mlstChildren;
```

In my method to append a child node:

```
void clsXMLnode::appendChild(clsXMLnode* pobjChild) {
assert(pobjChild != NULL);
mlstChildren.append(pobjChild);
// ...
```

When I use the debugger to single step I can see that `pobjChild` has all the static data that it should have associated with it, however the node that is appended to 'mlstChildren' has none of the static members.  Using the debugger I can see the 'pobjChild' is still correct and 'mlstChildren' whilst it has the same pointer address for the child node, the contents of it do not match the contents of 'pobjChild', why?

**Edit:**
It seems to be a bug in the debugger, I modified my `appendChild` method as follows:

```
void clsXMLnode::appendChild(clsXMLnode* pobjChild) {
assert(pobjChild != NULL);
int intNewIdx = mlstChildren.length();
mlstChildren.append(pobjChild);
clsXMLnode* pobjCheck = mlstChildren.at(intNewIdx);
// ...
```

I can see in the debugger that the contents of `pobjCheck` matches the contents of `pobjChild` exactly and all static members are intact, but if I expand `mlstChildren` in the debugger, whilst the class address matches `pobjChild`, the contents of the static data does not.

Comment: What do you mean by "static data"? Do you mean static member variables? But those aren't actually members of any specific object, instead all objects (instances) of that class have those.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I have a load of static pointers defined in the class, for example: const char clsXMLnode::mcszAutosize[]                      = "autosize";  Static data should be common to all instances of the class, but for some reason in the debugger when I look at the list, the static data shows as ""

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, see question edit, looks like a bug in the debugger.

Comment: I was just thinking that myself. What IDE/debugger are you using?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I'm working on RedHat 7.2, using QtCreator 4.3.1

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I have posted on the Qt Forum to report the issue.  https://forum.qt.io/topic/82279/debugger-and-static-data

Comment: Rather than edit the answer into your question, can you put it in an answer please?  (It is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question - the *only* wrinkle is that you don't get the rep-bonus for accepting your own answer :-) )

Comment: @MartinBonner, there is no answer, it is still a problem, I've posted on Qt forum, to report what I believe to be a bug.

Comment: Why is it a problem?  Just don't look at the function parameter when inspecting the class static values.  (When you says "static data should be common to all instances of the class", I disagree.  I would say "static data does not belong to *any* instance of the class", it's a wrinkle that you can say `pObjChild->mcszAutosize` rather than `clsXMLnode::mcszAutosize` - but I would avoid that anyway.)

Comment: @MartinBonner, in c++ as in Java static members are common to all instances of that type, that is a fact, if you disagree then go read up on static members.

Comment: @SPlatten : I am well aware of the semantics of the C++ language.  What we are arguing about is how to describe those semantics.  My view is that saying the static members are "common to all instances" is unhelpful.  You obviously find it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really an answer, however I think I've proven that it is one of several ongoing bugs in the Qt Debugger, which I have reported to the Qt developers forum:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/82279/debugger-and-static-data